# SCons env.Command() doesn't work as expected, no command executed

Tags: command, environment-variables, output, echo, scons

I've got a simple SConstruct file as below:

```
import os,sys
env = Environment()

env.Command([], [], "echo abc")
```

I expected that this will output "abc", but in fact, nothing extra is printed, the screen output is:

```
$scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```

So how should I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've called a builder with no source and no targets, it's never out of date, and so won't be run.

So you want it to run right away, in which case you should use `Execute()`

```
env = Environment()
env.Execute("echo abc")
```

or just

```
Execute("echo abc")
```

The latter yields

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
echo abc
abc
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `.' is up to date.
scons: done building targets.
```